# SQL access to GEOPackage data

Tags: qgis, sql, geopackage

I am new to the world of QGIS. I work for a company that records birds in order to prepare expert reports. I am actually a programmer and would like to make my life a little easier when analysing the data.

I would like to query the data via SQL and build something from it. We use GEOPackages.

Is there a way to access the data in QGIS via SQL or from outside via a driver?

Comment: sure use the DB manager

Comment: To expend on @IanTurton comment Geopackage (https://www.geopackage.org/) are a special kind of SQLite/Spatialite database so any tool that you may use with SQLite will work to access and query the data

Comment: For outside access use GDAL ~ https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#raster-gpkg and https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html#vector-gpkg

Comment: Historically, python has been used a lot in the GIS world, so the ecosystem is well developed. There are many, but this is an example of a "getting started": https://pythongis.org. QGIS also offers a python API: [PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html). If you consider python, feel free to ask more info on what are easy ways to leverage your SQL knowledge.

Comment: Specifically for directly accessing the data inside a GeoPackage, I've found using [db browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) more enlightening than reading [the geopackage spec](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/), but both should work.